# How do I manipulate and resend an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I have an Observable (*commonSrv.uiMessage*) which I am listening to. When it fires I show a message to the user (*this.snackBar.open*) and receive a ref (*snackBarRef*) as a result. When the user clicks on the message, *onAcation()* is fired and I receive a new Observable.

I want to take this Observable returned from *snackBarRef.onAction()* and listen to it somewhere else.

```
commonSrv.uiMessage.subscribe((msg) => {
          let snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open(msg.text , msg.actionTxt);
          snackBarRef.onAction().subscribe(() => {
            alert('The snack-bar action was triggered!');
          });
        })
```

I know I can't send an Observable from within a subscription, so this does not work

```
let x = new Observable<any>()
      commonSrv.uiMessage.subscribe((msg) => {
      let snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open(msg.text , msg.actionTxt);
      x = snackBarRef.onAction()
    });

    x.subscribe(a=> alert(a))
```

I should probably use pipe and map to funnel the original Observable but am not sure of the syntax or which operators are suitable (map? switchMap?)

Answer (score 2):

You should use [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) operator in order to switch to a new observable after each subscription.

```js
const onAction: Observable<any> = commonSrv.uiMessage.pipe(
   switchMap((msg: any) => {
      const snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open(msg.text, msg.actionTxt);
      return snackBarRef.onAction();
   ),
);

onAction.subscribe(
   () => {
      console.log('Click!');
   }
);
```

Shorter one:

```js
const onAction: Observable<any> = commonSrv.uiMessage.pipe(
   switchMap((msg: any) => this.snackBar.open(msg.text, msg.actionTxt).onAction()),
);

onAction.subscribe(() => console.log('Click!'));
```

- I recommend using more types for your functions params and variables.
- Also very important to `unsubscribe()` your subscriptions when finish using them.
- Notice that `switchMap` kills previous `switchMap`s subscriptions (HTTP requests for example) - if you wish to keep them "alive" - use [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) instead.

**Addition:**
If you wish to receive both of the observable's values, you can use [withLatestFrom](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom) operator:

```js
const onAction: Observable<any> = commonSrv.uiMessage.pipe(
   withLatestFrom(this.snackBar.open(msg.text, msg.actionTxt).onAction()),
);

onAction.subscribe(([value1, value2]) => console.log(`first: ${value1} | second: {$value2}`));
```

Comment: That worked! What if I want to keep the value of the first Obs (msg) , but emit the updated obs whet the second (onAction) fires? at the moment the first value is lost

Answer (score 1):

You thought in a right way. You need to use switchMap and map pipes. If I were you I would create the following

```
const snackBarAction$ = commonSrv.uiMessage.pipe(
  map(msg => this.snackBar.open(msg.text , msg.actionTxt)),
  switchMap(snackBarRef => snackBarRef.onAction()),
  shareReplay(1)
)
```

Since you subscribed on `snackBarAction$`, it is listening to `uiMessage`. And when such message received, snack bar  would be opened and "switch" your subscription to `onAction()` changes.

Notice, that `this.snackBar.open` is kind of side effect, which can cause undesired behaviour: 
If you get several messages from `uiMessage` observable, this method would be called several times. You might need to close it every new message received. To cover this case you can use `tap` operator.
If you want to reuse this observable somewhere else, another subscription would call all these pipe operators again. If it doesn't suits you, use `shareReplay` operator, it also preserves last emmited value.